# polymorphism with templated class function and type casting

Tags: c++

Some code block so I can explain my two problems:

```
namespace shapes
{

enum ShapeType
{
   Cylinder,
   Sphere,
...
}

     class Shape
    {
     // ...
     ShapeType type;
    };
    class Sphere : public Shape
    {
    ..
    }
    class Cylinder : public Shape
    {
    ..
    }

} // End of namespace shapes
    -----------------------------
      template<> 
      struct std::hash<shapes::Sphere>
      {
        std::size_t operator()(const shapes::Sphere& s) const 
        {
          std::size_t h = 0;
          boost::hash_combine(h, std::hash<std::string>{}(shapes::Sphere::STRING_NAME));
          boost::hash_combine(h, std::hash<double>{}(s.radius));
          return h;
        }
      };

      // Similar implementation with Cylinder

      template<>
      struct std::hash<shapes::Shape>
      {
        std::size_t operator()(const shapes::Shape &shape) const
        {
          switch (shape.type)
          {
            case shapes::CYLINDER:
            {
              auto c = dynamic_cast<const shapes::Cylinder&>(shape);
              return std::hash<shapes::Cylinder>{}(c);
            }
            case shapes::SPHERE:
            {
              auto s = dynamic_cast<const shapes::Sphere&>(shape);
              return std::hash<shapes::Sphere>{}(s);
            }
            ....
          }
        }
      };
```

Problem #1:
Since I couldn't use above with virtual keyword like we do with polymorphism
this didn't work
`boost::hash_combine(h, std::hash<shape>{}(a.getShape())` -> This always calls the
base `shape` hash. Can someone please confirm that above will always call base class
and no virtual table would help there?

Problem #2:
Even though the `operator()` argument is shape reference somehow my compiler doesn't
know that. It thinks it is value and so I can't do static/dynamic casting. Am I reading wrong?

Comment: What's `Shape`? How, if at all, is it related to class `shape`?

Comment: You could define a virtual `ComputeHash` function in `Shape`, and override it in derived classes. Then `std::hash<shapes::Shape>::operator()` would simply do `return shape.ComputeHash();`. Et voila, you have your polymorphism.

Comment: You say you have a problem with `getShape()`, but you don't show its definition or even declaration. My guess would be, it returns by value and you experience [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). To avoid guessing, show a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean, you can't do static/dynamic casting? What happens when you try? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? Again, show a [mcve]. If your program fails to compile, show the full and complete text of any error messages you receive. If your program compiles but produces incorrect results when run, show the expected output, the actual output, and explain how the two differ.

Comment: Oops. I think I kept some namespaces there. @IgorTandetnik you're right about writting `ComputeHash` that's my last resort.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated code with namespace. Weirdly enough I'm no more getting error of `dynamic_cast const target is not pointer or reference` . May be it was late night yesterday. I would still like your opinion in going with overloading `std::hash` vs writting `ComputeHash`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. If you hope that `std::hash<Shape>{}(a.getShape())` could somehow magically instantiate `std::hash<Sphere>` instead of `std::hash<Shape>`, then that's not going to work. You explicitly specify which class to instantiate, there's no room for interpretation. Once you resign yourself to calling `std::hash<shape>::operator()`, the question becomes - why are you hand-rolling a homegrown virtual dispatch, when there's a perfectly fine one built into the language?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that templated class call (`std::hash<Shape>{}(a.getShape())`) will always call the type I instantiated! But I dont understand your comment: "the question becomes - why are you hand-rolling a homegrown virtual dispatch, when there's a perfectly fine one built into the language? "

Comment: Your switch on type and dynamic casts are in effect an attempt to simulate a virtual function call. Why not just, you know, define a virtual function and then call it?

Comment: I tried declaring `virtual std::hash<Shape>()(const Shape& s);` but that didn't work. Unless you're implying I should go with writing function call `HashCompute`

Comment: The only reason I didn't go adding a function like `ComputeHash` is because `Shape` is in library and I wanted to avoid modifying that (I could just wanted to avoid)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was implying. However, now that I think of it - how do you plan to use that hash function? If you are thinking of something like `std::unordered_set<Shape>`, then that would hold instances of `Shape`, not `Sphere` or `Cylinder`; it won't be polymorphic. What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik. I'm trying to use this two ways (1) Create hash-map of my object (which uses `Shape` and many other things). It is costly to create that object. (2) Really compare two objects with their hash.

Comment: How does your object use `Shape`? Compare two objects of what types? It would be best if you show the example of the usage you have in mind.